# Disable Warning 1591 message in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How to disable Warning #1591 message in VS 2010? Now I get Error List filled up wore than 200 such messages. I would like not to have them here. I use XML comment on some of class properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go into the project properties, the Build tab and in the "Suppress warnings" text box, enter 1591.

See [this blog post](http://harborsparrow.blogspot.com/2007/12/suppressing-vsnet-2005-compiler.html) for more details (and a screenshot, albeit from VS2005) of exactly this case.